# In Firefox xpath not showing detail (relative) xpath for any element

Tags: firefox, xpath, firebug, relative-path, firepath

Firefox not showing relative xpath for any element. I am using Firefox version 56.0(32 bit)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the result? Also, do you really mean Firebug or actually the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has a problem with the latest version of Firefox(56.0).You need to downgrade your firefox for the version to solve this.Alternatively, you can use chrome to verify XPath

You can copy xpath:
[image]
You can open a Console in Chrome, and check the XPath by typing `$x("your_xpath_here")`. This will return an array of matched values. If it is empty, you know there is no match on the page.

For example:
[image]

Comment: What is that problem you mention?

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox DevTools copy the *absolute* XPath when you right-click an element within the Inspector and choose *Copy* > *XPath* from the context menu.

That's the same what Firebug did. Only FirePath (a Firebug extension for creating XPaths and CSS selectors) and the Chrome DevTools create a relative path to the selected element.

I have now filed [bug 1410810](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410810) asking to adjust the Firefox DevTools to also create a relative XPath.